# Scroll ScrollView under ImageView

Tags: android, scrollview, ontouchlistener

Is it possible to scroll `ScrollView` that actually lay under `ImageView` using gestures?
**Layout example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/ll_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">
             <!--..some content..-->
       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

---

If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it works without any additional code :)
[Video approve](http://sendvid.com/f2clmdjx).

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the touchEvent from ImageView to ScrollView like below.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return scrollView.onTouchEvent(event);
    } 
});
```